# Material You icon on PWA

Tags: android, web, icons, progressive-web-apps, manifest

is there some way to implement monochrome icon to the PWA manifest, for android to use it with themed icon, in the new Material You design?
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/icon_design_adaptive
this but in PWA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the [purpose `monochrome` (W3 reference)](https://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/#dfn-monochrome) is what you are looking for.

Simply add your icon in your manifest like so:

```json
{
  …
  "icons": [
    …
    {
      "src": "path/to/monochrome_icon.png",
      "sizes": "196x196",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "monochrome"
    },
    …
  ],
  …
}
```

Note that this feature is still not widely implemented. Here is an [ongoing issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1468845) asking for the support of this feature on Chrome mobile.

[More details about `monochrome` icons](https://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/#monochrome-icons-and-solid-fills).

You will need to make your icon fully black and transparent for it to work properly.

Comment: I tried this and android will not use this icon when switch to themed icons. Are there any know captachs?

Comment: Yes, I did open an issue for the chrome dev team about this https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1468845

But monochrome icons are also used on other use-cases too.